# Add a row made of 0 for each identifier in a large database

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, rbind

I have a database where the first row of each of the unique identifiers is missing. 
Basically, I need to add for each unique id a new row made of 0.

My database looks like that (I have more than a million rows, so loops are basically impossible).

```
dt = as.data.frame( rbind(c('A1', '15', '1'), 
  c('A1', '17', '2'), 
  c('A1', '12', '3'), 
  c('B1', '3', '1'), 
  c('B1', '4', '2'), 
  c('B1', '15', '3')))

colnames(dt) = c('id', 'activity', 'time')
```

For each id, I need to add a 0 line, at time 0.

The following line of codes works, however, it takes too much time for my database.

```
IdUnique = length(unique(dt$id))
VeK = vector('list',  IdUnique)
for(i in 1:IdUnique){  
  row0 = matrix(0, nrow = 1, ncol = ncol(dt), dimnames = list(unique(dt$id)[i], colnames(dt)))
  VeK[[i]] = rbind(row0, subset(dt, id == unique(dt$id)[i]) )
  VeK[[i]][,'id'] <- unique(dt$id)[i]
}

dt2 <- do.call("rbind", VeK)
```

I was wondering if there was not a more economic solution, like merging by rows 
and by id. But I can not figure out how to do it.

```
mat = matrix(0, nrow = length(unique(dt$id)), ncol = ncol (dt) ) 
colnames(mat) <- colnames(dt)

mat[, 'id'] <- as.character(unique(dt$id))
mat <- as.data.frame(mat)

merge(mat, dt, by = 'id' )
```

Any solutions to merge by rows and controlling for identifier ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(activity = 0, time = 0) %>% 
  merge(., dt, all = T) %>%
  arrange(id, time)
```

Or:

```
dt %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(as.character(0))) %>% 
  full_join(., dt) %>%
  arrange(id, time)
```

Which gives:

```
#  id activity time
#1 A1        0    0
#2 A1       15    1
#3 A1       17    2
#4 A1       12    3
#5 B1        0    0
#6 B1        3    1
#7 B1        4    2
#8 B1       15    3
```

Afterwards, if you want to convert the `activity` and `time` columns to numeric you could add:

```
... %>% mutate_each(funs(type.convert(as.character(.))), -id)
```

**Update**

If the class difference wasn't made on purpose in your original `dt`, it would be a bit easier:

```
dt <- data.frame(id = c(rep("A1", 3), rep("B1", 3)),
                 activity = c(15,17,12,3,4,15),
                 time = rep(1:3, 2))

library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(activity = 0, time = 0) %>% 
  full_join(., dt) %>%
  arrange(id, time)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Could you just update me about the 
    %>%  
sign ?

Comment: @giacomoV Glad it helped ! Take a look at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html

Answer (score 2):

```
dt = as.data.frame( rbind(c('A1', '15', '1'), 
                          c('A1', '17', '2'), 
                          c('A1', '12', '3'), 
                          c('B1', '3', '1'), 
                          c('B1', '4', '2'), 
                          c('B1', '15', '3')
                          ))

colnames(dt) = c('id', 'activity', 'time')
#Just we need to get the levels of `id` we want to bind `zeros` to
levels <- levels(dt$id)

#create a new matrix of new data we need to append to our data frame `dt`
levels_M <- cbind(id = levels , activity =  '0' , time = '0')

#then simply bind these values to the data frame
rbind(dt , levels_M)

#if you want to order the final results

dt <- dt[order(dt$id),]
```

for ordering also you can use `data.table` library , of course it will be faster than `base R` ordering

Answer (score 1):

First, I guess you have to convert your `dt` in such a way that both `activity` and `time` are of class `int` instead of `factor`:

```
dt[]<-lapply(dt,function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))
```

Then, you can use `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
DT<-as.data.table(dt)
DT[,lapply(.SD,function(x) c(0,x)),by=id]
```

Comment: I didn't use the `dt` provided in the OP, but the one I posted above. The `dt` is pretty strange, in the sense that each column is of type `factor`. I'm gonna add a couple of lines to show how to convert `dt` in a "proper" format.

Comment: Yes, I also edited to add a conversion step afterwards.

Comment: Another option is `setDT(dt)[, .SD[c((.N+1), 1:.N)], id][is.na(activity), 2:3 :=0L][]` assuming that the class is numeric